# How to change my background theme in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I change the theme in my android studio and it changes in all places, except in the background and in the code style, does anyone know how to change in these places, below I left a print to see that the code style is pretty ugly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Follow Below steps -

```
Go to File and click on Settings.
Under the Appearance & Behaviour -> Appearance, find Theme.
Choose the Default theme from the drop-down and click on Apply and then Ok.
Here you can see the background and color scheme for all three themes.
```